# Splitting a line to the edges

Tags: multicolumn, split

I am trying to prepare a multiple choice test sample using article documentclass. At the top of each test, I want it to write the test number and the topic of the test, but these two should be separated to the both edges of the paper, as seen in the picture. Currently I am doing it by using the following code:

```
    \noindent\fbox{%                                                                                                                                                                                          
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%                                                                                                                                                                                 
      Test No: 001 \hspace{14cm} Topic: Elements
  }%                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 }
```

but it is not efficient since I need to change the space for each topic. Is there any way to optimize this space between the test number and the topic ?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers.[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without the code that produces that, but perhaps `\hfill` does the trick.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I am looking for. I will edit my question and include the code.

Comment: @marmot add it as an answer. I know, it will be a short answer but in this way the post doesn't appear in the unanswered ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\parbox` is not needed (and actually somewhat wrong for the purpose):

```
\noindent\framebox[\textwidth][s]{Test No: 001\hfill Topic: Elements}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent\framebox[\textwidth][s]{Test No: 001\hfill Topic: Elements}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent\textbf{Question 1.}

\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just use `\hfill`.

```
\noindent\fbox{%                                                                                                                                                                                          
\parbox{\textwidth}{%                                                                                                                                                                                 
  Test No: 001\hfill Topic: Elements
}%                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```